# How to use offline map via OSMdroid?

Tags: android, offline, osmdroid

I've recently created an app via android studio to show offline map. I downloaded tiles.zip from atlas creator and the path is like this

```
└── MapquestOSM
    ├── 10
    │   └── 550
    │       └── 335.png
    ├── 11
    │   └── 1100
    │       └── 671.png
    ├── 12
    │   └── 2200
    │       └── 1343.png
    ├── 13
    │   ├── 4400
    │   │   ├── 2686.png
    │   │   └── 2687.png
    │   └── 4401
    │       ├── 2686.png
    │       └── 2687.png
```

then I Put the ZIP archive tiles.zip to the sdcard:

```
/mnt/sdcard/osmdroid/tiles.zip
```

my code file is like this :

```
public static final GeoPoint BERLIN = new GeoPoint(52.516667, 13.383333);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);

        mapView.setTileSource(new XYTileSource("MapquestOSM",
                ResourceProxy.string.mapnik, 0, 18, 256, ".jpg", new String[] {
                "http://otile1.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/",
                "http://otile2.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/",
                "http://otile3.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/",
                "http://otile4.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/"}));

        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
        mapView.setUseDataConnection(false); //optional, but a good way to prevent loading from the 
        network and test your zip loading.
        IMapController mapController = mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(15);
        GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(BERLIN);
        mapController.setCenter(startPoint);
    }
```

after running app I see just gridview and tiles do not show!
my log is :

```
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f4585849640: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7f458580c700)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f4585849640: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7f458580c700)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f4585849640: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7f458580c700)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f4585849640: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7f458580c700)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f4585849640: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7f458580c700)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f4585849640: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7f458580c700)
I/MapTileProviderBase: rescale tile cache from 8 to 7
I/MapTileProviderBase: Finished rescale in 8ms
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f4585849640: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7f458580c700)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f4585849640: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7f458580c700)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f4585849640: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7f458580c700)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f4585849640: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7f458580c700)
I/MapTileProviderBase: rescale tile cache from 7 to 6
I/MapTileProviderBase: Finished rescale in 17ms
```

I don't know where I've made mistake!!?

Answer (score 0):

The tile zip needs to be on the device somewhere. Be forewarned that the zip file has a limit on most versions of android (65k files), therefore a sqlite database is the preferred setup (and it's faster).

Your test app would then need to have permissions to read the zip/sqlite file. This varies based on device and android version number. By default, it looks like /sdcard/osmdroid. It is read initially when the map view is created. This location can be overridden using the Configuration.getInstance().set methods. You can also override and/or force rescans by resetting the tile provider chain. MapView.setTileProvider(...)

Finally, there's a number of debug options you can turn on to get more debugging output to log cat. I'm pretty sure you'll want to turn it on via Configuration.getInstance().set methods...anything related to tile loading/downloading will probably help.